# Have an editable matrix in MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Im using MVC and Razor to develop an application for administrative purposes. Using the model shown below, im trying to display a matrix that the user can edit. For each row, there is a start and an end value, the same is true for each column. In the example below, the X would be a start and the Y would be the end for a set value. The X, Y and the individual cells are editable. I do however feel that my solution might be way to coplex so any suggestion for a simple way to implement this would be welcome.

Example of what i want to accomplish:

```
    |         | XB | XB | XB |
    |         | YB | YB | YB |
    | XA | YA | 1  | 2  | 3  |
    | XA | YA | 3  | 4  | 5  |
    | XA | YA | 1  | 2  | 3  |
    | XA | YA | 3  | 4  | 5  |
```

The model:

```
    public class Item 
    {
        public string StartA { get; set; } // XA
        public string EndA   { get; set; } // YA
        public string StartB { get; set; } // XB
        public string EndB   { get; set; } // YB
        public string Value  { get; set; } // cell content
    }
```

The view:

```
    @model Item[]

    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Edit", null, new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Post" }, new { @class = "form-inline" }))
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
        {
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].StartA)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].EndA)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].StartB)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].EndB)
            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x[i].Value)
        }

        <hr />

        <table id="table1" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 8px; border:2px solid  gray;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => new { Start = x.StartA, End = x.EndA }))
                    {
                        <td>
                            <input size="3" name="sa" value="@group.Key.Start" />
                        </td>
                    }
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td></td>
                    @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => new { Start = x.StartA, End = x.EndA }))
                    {
                        <td><input size="3" name="ea" value="@group.Key.End" /></td>
                    }
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var group in Model.GroupBy(x => new { Start = x.StartB, End = x.EndB }))
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td><input size="3" name="sb" value="@group.Key.Start" /></td>
                        <td><input size="3" name="eb" value="@group.Key.End" /></td>
                        @foreach (var cell in group)
                        {
                            <td style="color: coral; font-weight: bold"><input size="3" name="value" value="@cell.Value" /></td>
                        }
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
    }
```

Question: im not sure how to bind the fields to the view, since the model (array of items) is used to generate the headers (row and column definitions, the X and Y cells) as well. When the binding works, i should also be able to add rows and colums.

Answer (score 0):

You can only bind named inputs.  So you can't bind an input to some position in an array of Items.

Probably the best way to make this work is to use three hidden fields.  One to store the number of rows, one for the number of columns, and one for a comma separated list of numbers.  When the user clicks save have some javascript copy all the numbers into the hidden fields.

Your model would need to be a single object rather then an array.  The model would have variables that have the same name of the hidden fields.  I would put the Item array in ViewBag.  You could have the Item array as a member of the model and use that to build your html so it can have strong type checking.  You'll just ignore it on the postback since it'll be null.

Comment: So what would the contents of the three hidden fields look like for example? I think that the data structure boils down to basically the same. You will need to store the xa, ya, xb, yb values somewhere as well. In the end, your values will be comma separated whereas the current model uses an array for that. I dont really care for that however i fail to see how that solves my problem.

Comment: Well, for your example above the values would be row: 3, columns: 3, values: 1,2,3,3,4,5,1,2,3,3,4,5.  Your problem, unless I misunderstood, is you need a method that lets you post the data back.  My suggestion allows for that.  Of course you will have to parse the text on postback.  You can use string.Split() to do most of that.  Alternatively, you could use JSON or Xml instead and use built in libraries to parse the data.  That'll probably be overkill unless you expect more complex data down the road.